# How to get a substring with regex in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the content between apostrophes but I messed up something most likely because I only get `null`.

```
string.match(/_\('*'\)/)
```

I need to get `OK` from this `"_('OK')"`

Comment: Use `/_\('([^']*)'\)/`

Comment: [JavaScript text between double quotes](//stackoverflow.com/q/19793221), [Find Text Between 2 Quotes with jQuery](//stackoverflow.com/q/1684116), [Javascript regex to extract all characters between quotation marks following a specific word](//stackoverflow.com/q/24901063)

Comment: `"_('OK')".match(/_\('([^']*)'\)/)[1]`

Comment: When you are facing problems with regex, [RegEx101](https://www.regex101.com/r/Nrc8TL/1) is where you should try out the regex. Check the "Explanation" tab on the right top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use a (sub)pattern to match any chars but `'` zero/one or more times + you need to *capture* the contents in between single quotes to later access the Group 1 contents after getting the match with `String#match`:

```js
var s = "_('OK')";
var res = s.match(/_\('([^']*)'\)/);
if (res) {
  console.log(res[1]);  
}
```